# Creating screenshots for Windows Phone 8 apps without the emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

My laptop's processor doesn't support SLAT so I can't run the WP8 emulator on my laptop and use that to take screenshots.

I have a Lumia 920 and I can take screenshots with it, but only for one of the three screen sizes available on Windows Phone.

Is there any way to take screenshots for all the different screen sizes in this case?

Comment: The simulator doesn't have to run "decent". It just has to run well enough to get the shot you need. So what if getting a screenshot was a laggy and painful experience... it's not something your users will ever see. If you can make it run at all, then go that route.

Comment: the simulator doesn't have to run decent, it just DOES need to run however, if you read my question correctly. it doesn't run ON decent PCs. my pc has 2.26 GHz Core 2 Duo processor, 256GB SSD, 8GB RAM. and guess what: just because it's processor doesn't support a very new technology called SLAT, i can't run the simulator. at all.

Comment: Ah, I did miss a word. Oops. It happens.

Comment: one decent app is screen capture, have you try it

Comment: The question about running emulator on WP8 SDK for non-SLAT processors has been done to death already... (the answer is still no)

Comment: @radoslaf does it allow one to take screenshots for different screen sizes?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts any workarounds for taking screenshots? (maybe something on the phone that would emulate different screen size etc?)

Comment: You can downscale using a photo-editing app from 1280x768 to 800x480 as that is the same aspect ratio but it's probably not worth it as the Marketplace will probably do that for you. Apart from asking a contact to take a screenshot, you may end up figuring out if it is cheaper to buy an HTC 8X or a cheap Core i3 machine.

Comment: I still don't have a solution for 720p. i ended up in a very ugly "solution" where I scaled a 768p image to 720, changing its aspect ratio. but it's still a workaround, otherwise i can't submit my app to the store because of a missing 720p screenshot that I am unable to create.

Comment: worst case scenario if you want you can send me your xap and i will take the screen shoots for you

Comment: thank you, but this time i've already submitted. but really, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. There is not a way to have your Lumia 920 render in a different resolution if that's what you're asking. This makes verifying those resolutions pretty tough. It really makes you have to trust in your layout that your application can scale correctly.

To get the screenshots, I used my Lumia 920 to take screenshots, then I used paint.net to resize the images to the correct sizes for the store requirements. It's a little misleading to the user but it's all you can do without having the devices you need to test.

Other options would be to reach out to your local Microsoft developer evangelist to see if you can get a  device to test those resolutions. Then if all else fails and you're still not comfortable shipping your app without testing on those resolutions you can always find a developer friend that is willing to run your app on their emulator.

Comment: yes, i ended up the same scaling way. 480x800 and 768x1280 is the same aspect ratio. i ended up strectching that image for the 720p too, which i definitely hate, but unfortunatelly, i was optionless because of microsoft..

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a Windows Phone 8, you can just press the Power and Start buttons simultaneously to take a screenshot.